# Need help with low power audio amplifier circuit

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, batteries, pcb-design, audio

I intend to output an 8-bit waveform generated on an ATtiny1614 microcontroller running at 3.3 V to a 1-2 W, 4-8 ohm speaker and have the user able to change the volume.

For that, I am thinking about using the SSM2211SZ or TS4962 audio amplifier IC by supplying it at 5V and having the MCU DAC as positive input and ground as negative input.

Also, in order to digitally change the volume without losing sound quality, I am planning to use the MCP41100 100 kohm digital potentiometer (hooked up to the ATtiny) to adjust the amplifier gain (or connect the wiper to amplifier positive input and the A pin to the DAC?), and disable the DAC peripheral to mute the device.

Can you please tell me if this approach will work, and provide a schematic for such a circuit? Thank you.

Comment: sure send $50 to charity or go to Adafruit

Comment: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX9744.pdf

Comment: Kozma, the TDA8551 is a 5 V, BTL IC designed to cover something in the range you specify for output. It uses digital pulses to increase or decrease the volume, which would allow your MCU to do that work easily. This allows you many options for volume control. It would likely accept your MCU DAC output, though I've not done any leg work for you on that score. I'm just making another suggestion of something to consider.

Comment: @jonk Thank you, I will consider that!

Answer (score 1):

- You're forgetting you need an (analog!) reconstruction filter after your DAC
- Using an external variable attenuator to modify audio that's digital to begin with is, mildly put, a bit unusual. Don't do that. Instead, simply modify the signal you're playing: a halving of sample values is but -6 dB volume, pretty benign.
- While we're at it: you're (probably/hopefully) oversampling; that increases your dynamic range immensely. Again, no matter what you do, but especially here, appropriate reconstruction filtering (anti-imaging filtering) is a *necessity*. You need that.
- nobody will use a 4Ω speaker (relatively hi-fi) to get 1 W output power from an 8 bit system. Make sure you're spec'ing something sensible – I bet you've got that from some vendor claiming "I can do 3 W into 4 Ω at 5 V supply" or so: Sure, you can, but reading the fine print yields they say, often, "at 10% THD". Well, you don't need much of a well-designed amplifier to yield that level of distortion. Relevant numbers are what the chip can do at < 1% THD, typically at 0.1% THD.
- It might totally be that you're looking for that "rasp" 8bit-era distorted sound that actually comes from distortion (mostly due to synthesizing stuff with square waves, which inherently have serious harmonics). In that case, maybe don't use a DAC but actually generate a PWM that you then amplify with a MOSFET bridge to "hard" 5V/0V, and only slightly filter the result.